# FindViewById in view but after loading fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I want to call findViewById in my ProfileActivity, which has three fragments, in one of these fragments, ProfileFragment, I put 4 empty TextView items so that I can change them according to the logged in user. I can't use getView().findViewById in the fragment because I need to call a large method which is found in the base class, which is extended by ProfileActivity so I can call it there. However, whenever I call findViewById in profileActivity in onCreate method, there is an error as the fragments are not yet created. Any suggestions where i should do this part?

```
public void setInfo(){

        //TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
        TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_name1);
        TextView age = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_age);
        TextView gender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_gender);
        TextView email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.profile_email);

        User u = getCurrentUser();

        //name.setText(u.getUserName());
        name1.setText("test");
        age.setText("test");
        email.setText("test");
        gender.setText("test");
    }
```

This code is in ProfileActivity right now and the 4 TextViews are in the fragment.

Comment: how in earth do you wanna access a view that is within a fragment? have you heard about fragment communication? if no. i suggest you do!

Comment: *how in earth do you wanna access a view that is within a fragment?* it is possible ... with findViewById ... the whole point is that fragment has to be attached ... (of course it doesn't make sens as Activity shouldn't know about fragment's View )

Comment: Pass the values using a constructor into `ProfileFragment`.

Comment: Fragment should have parameterless constructor!!!

Comment: I want the fragment to display the logged in user's name..How can I do that? I added empty textview to the fragment and change it when it is opened.

Comment: Your **Fragment** should have `setUser` method ... and in it's implementation **Fragment** should set the UI (and k0sh suggetion (while he is wrong that it is not possible) about learning on Activity<=>Fragment comunication is a good idea)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the values from `ProfileActivity` into you `ProfileFragment` when you instantiate it.

```
public static final ProfileFragment newInstance(String name, String age, String gender, String email)
{
    ProfileFragment f = new ProfileFragment();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
    bdl.putInt(EXTRA_NAME, name);
    bdl.putInt(EXTRA_AGE, age);
    bdl.putInt(EXTRA_GENDER, gender);
    bdl.putInt(EXTRA_EMAIL, email);
    f.setArguments(bdl);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    name = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_NAME);
    age = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_AGE);
    gender = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_GENDER);
    email = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_EMAIL);

    ...
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    setUser(view);

    ...

    return view;
}

private void setUser(View view){

    TextView name1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_name1);
    TextView age = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_age);
    TextView gender = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_gender);
    TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_email);

    name1.setText(name);
    age.setText(age);
    email.setText(gender);
    gender.setText(email);
}
```

and then use it like:

```
public void setInfo(){
  User u = getCurrentUser();
  get[Support]FragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_placehoder_id, ProfileFragment.newInstance(u.getName(), u.getAge(), u.getGender(), u.getEmail())).commit();
}
```

Comment: ok, but there will be some problem when he has his fragment in activity's layout(as you can't use setArguments in such case) ... so it this fragment should be create and added after he obtain the user information ...

Comment: Yeah, that depends when he actually loads the fragment. But its not actually clear from the question. Any improvements to add @Selvin?

Comment: I would add the creation of the fragment code in the answer (usage) ... This should be enough ... unless he would edit the question and make it more clear...

Answer (score -1):

You Must Have Create a java file in for fragment and a layout for that fragment like this:

```
 public class InvestorProfileFragment{
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.investor_profile_fragment, container, false);
    init(mRootView);
    return mRootView;
}
```

public void init(View view) {

```
    txvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_name);
```

}

and do what you want...

Comment: how this answer answers on the question how to get this TextBox from Activity?

Comment: from activity send data via set Agrument and use in fragment .can't play child untill he/she born